# ANR caused by service

Tags: android, android-service, android-anr-dialog

I have a service that starts a `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`.
Therefore, all the job done is done in a worker thread.
What is done in the thread is, retrieve a value from server, do some easy computation and save a value in SharedPreference.

Rarely, I get ANR, and log mesage tells it's caused by my service.
Do you have any idea why it can happens ?

Also, in case it matters, i sometime restart my Service (stopping it, which call shutdownNow() on the `ScheduledExecutorService`, and restarting it).

Here is the relevant part of code.

```
public void onCreate() {
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constant.SHARED_PREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
        broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        registerReceiver();

        if(scheduler == null) {
            scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay
                    (new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            android.util.Log.d(TAG, "globalLogic Scheduler started");
                            globalLogic();
                        }
                    }, 0, CHECK_PERIOD, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should take care of your `Service` because the `Service` normally runs in the `UIThread`:

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process; the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process unless you specify otherwise. If your service is going to perform any CPU-intensive work or blocking operations, such as MP3 playback or networking, you should create a new thread within the service to complete that work. By using a separate thread, you can reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors, and the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction with your activities.

There're 3 ways to solve your issues:

1. Using `IntentService`
2. Using thread inside your `Service`
3. Or make your `Service` runs in a different process as below:

   `<service
   android:name="com.example.appName"
   android:process=":externalProcess"/>`

> If the name assigned to this attribute begins with a colon (':'), a new process, private to the application, is created when it's needed and the service runs in that process. If the process name begins with a lowercase character, the service will run in a global process of that name, provided that it has permission to do so. This allows components in different applications to share a process, reducing resource usage.

You can read more about the Services [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know Service do run on the main UI thread. That's why i am using a newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(), which create a worker thread, doing a repetitive work, on a hour basis. So i'm doing your (2) advice

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use something like [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android)?
it's efficient and supports API level 9+.

Its only limitation is that it relies on Google Play Services.

> **Requirements**:
>   The FirebaseJobDispatcher currently relies on the scheduling component in Google Play services. Because of that, it won't work on environments without Google Play services installed.